# create Date Period selection parameter in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, powerbi-paginated-reports

I want to create a parameter named Date Period with values like Yesterday, This Week, Prior Week, This Month, Prior Month, Prior 3 months, Last Year.

I want to sure that these values can filter to real date range when selected from Date Period parameter. For example, when yesterday is selected then my report should return only yesterday data, similar with This Week, Prior Week, This Month, Prior Month, Prior 3 months, Last Year selection.

How can I create this in SSRS or Power BI paginated report linking Date Period parameter to real dates.

Comment: I would, personally, likely have a dataset that takes your parameter ("Date Period") and then returns 2 columns called `DateFrom` and `DateTo`, and these values can to assigned to the default values of said parameters (which I assume would be hidden). You could easily use a `CASE` expression within the SQL to achieve this. Alternatively you could to this inside SSRS with SSRS Expressions or Custom VB/C# code with a `Switch` statement (I'm just not a fan of SSRS Expressions and I'm terrible at C#).

Comment: @Larnu -  I really don't know how to do it but need help either by showing me a sample in order to understand it properly